# PHP: Parsing JSON with foreach()

Tags: php, json, web

I tried decoding a JSON file and display its contents.
My PHP code for this is:

```
<?php        
  $proj = json_decode(file_get_contents('projects.json'));
  foreach ($proj->projs as $p) {
    $name = $p->name;
    $auth = $p->author;
    $file = $p->filep;
    project($name, $auth, $file);
  }
?>
```

and my JSON file is:

```
{
    "projs": [
        {
            "name": "RGBFade",
            "author": "me",
            "filep": "rgbfade.txt"
        },
    ]
}
```

The `project()` function and the implementation of the JSON File works.

However, it throws this error:

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in index.php on line 38`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

If you would like to see the site, it's [here](http://www.foxat.de/f/arduino/index.php)

Comment: Have you debug it? What's coming in $proj->projects?

Comment: check with echo "<pre>"; print_r($proj->projects); die;

Comment: foreach ($proj->projs as $p) {

Comment: If your json property is `projs` why are you using `projects` -> `$proj->projects`?

Comment: @Roy that **was** a typo but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @DeveloperTK so, what is the problem?

Comment: there was a comma at the end of the array. I removed it but then it just shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its not valid json** because of the trailing `,` after the first object.

```
{
    "projects": [
        {
            "name": "RGBFade",
            "author": "me",
            "filep": "rgbfade.txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

https://3v4l.org/5U14v

Comment: @DeveloperTK Then your doing something else wrong. Working example: https://3v4l.org/F9Gvv

Comment: nevermind I found the solution: I needed to type `echo(project(...));` not `project(...);`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... Nothing special:
I should have used `echo(project(...));` not `project(...);`

Thanks to everyone who to helped me :)